# Spark worker in kubernetes cluster exits

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

Message on worker:

```
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO Worker: Executor app-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX/0 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 0
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX, execId=0)
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX/1 for truework.ScalaStreaming
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
21/10/15 17:00:16 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin/java" "-cp" "/spark/conf/:/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=XXXXX" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@127.0.0.1:XXXX" "--executor-id" "1" "--hostname" "127.0.0.1" "--cores" "1" "--app-id" "app-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@127.0.0.1:XXXXX
```

Anyone have this problem?

I believe it's these IP's because, I run it on kubernetes: microk8s kubectl.

Comment: Yes, the IP is the problem. You should be using k8s service names, not `127.0.0.1` as this would always resolve to the pod where the code runs, not the k8s API server / spark master

Comment: You now how change all the parameters? I know only change spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@127.0.0.1:XXXX using SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME

Comment: I've never ran Spark on Kubernetes, but I imagine you've followed some guide to set it up?

Comment: Yes. But this part is little confused for me. Because the old programador does this part so different.

Comment: I configure my spark working, and now i have problem code 143.

Comment: That is an OOM Error, so you need more memory or configure your job to use less